# How to get my computer to turn off when the lid is closed

Tags: software-installation

I am having a problem with shutting down the computer. I have looked in the settings, and nothing will give me the same options to mimic what apple would make your computer do after you closed it. I want my computer, once closed, to not keep the screen on and such inside the computer. I want it to turn off everything and power down, without me having to restart the computer the next time I do something. This would be extremely helpful to me because my computer doesn't last long without a plug on Elementary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your computer to shut down if you close the lid (and this separately for *Plugged in* and *On Battery* modes).

However I don't really understand how can you not have to restart the computer the next time you want to use it: if you power it off, you will have to power it on eventually if you want to use it again…

Unlock *Settings / Power* and set *Shutdown* as lid close action.

[image: setting shutdown on lid close]